# Django Form does not show up until it's submitted

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I made a form in Django, but it's not showing up before it's been submitted.

The forms.py looks like this

```
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from productapp.models import User
from django import forms


class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(
        max_length=100, help_text='Required. Add a valid email address!!', label='Email')
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, label='Name')
    password1 = forms.PasswordInput()
    password2 = forms.PasswordInput()

    class Meta:
        model = User

        fields = ('email', 'name', 'password1', 'password2')

        # email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100, help_text='required')


The views.py file looks like this:

    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .tokens import account_activation_token
from .forms import SignUpForm
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode, urlsafe_base64_decode
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import default_token_generator
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate

# Create your views here.

from productapp.models import User

UserModel = get_user_model()
# Create your views here.


def signup(request):
    print(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'authentication/register.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        print(form.is_valid())
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.normaluser = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Activate your account.'
            message = render_to_string('authentication/email_template.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(
                mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
            )
            email.send()
            return HttpResponse('Please confirm your email address to complete the registration')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'authentication/register.html', {'form': form})


def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64).decode()
        user = UserModel._default_manager.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and default_token_generator.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        return HttpResponse('Thank you for your email confirmation. Now you can login your account.')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')


def register(request):
    context = {}
    if request.POST:
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            account = authenticate(email=email, password=raw_password)
            login(request, account)
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            context['form'] = form
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
        context['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'authentication/register.html', context)
```

And this is what the template looks like.

```
   {% extends 'index.html' %}
<!-- {%load crispy_forms_tags %} -->

{% block content %}
<div style="display:flex;justify-content: center;flex-direction: row;">

    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <center>
            <h3>Sign Up</h3>
        </center>
        <!-- {{form|crispy}} -->
        <!-- {{form.as_p}} -->
        {% for field in form %}
        <p>
            {{field.name.capitalize}}
            {{ field }}
            {% for error in field.errors %}
        <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
        </p>
        {% endfor %}

        <center><button class='btn btn-primary' type="submit">Sign up</button>
        </center>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

This is what the url looks like when you first visit it.
[Picture of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aascr.png)

And this is what it looks like after submission.
[Picture of the form after submission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSOYf.png)

Comment: In your view `signup`, for a GET request you are not passing anything as the context. See these two lines: `if request.method == 'GET':` and `return render(request, 'authentication/register.html')` (Simply remove these two lines, you already have an `else` block handling the case of the request not being a POST request)

Answer (score 2):

it seems your first `if` statement in `signup` function is redundant.

```
if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'authentication/register.html')
```

you don't send `form` variable to the template in these lines. this is why form is not shown in the template. just remove it. you already send your `form` in the last line of your function:

```
return render(request, 'authentication/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

do this in your views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .tokens import account_activation_token
from .forms import SignUpForm
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode, urlsafe_base64_decode
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import default_token_generator
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate

# Create your views here.

from productapp.models import User

UserModel = get_user_model()
# Create your views here.


def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.normaluser = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Activate your account.'
            message = render_to_string('authentication/email_template.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(
                mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
            )
            email.send()
            return HttpResponse('Please confirm your email address to complete the registration')

        #what should the function return if the form has errors
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
        return render(request, 'authentication/register.html', {'form': form})
```